# Calculus Integral from Partial Fractions

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

When you have an irreducible quadratic factor repeated you can get integrals that look like $\int \dfrac{dx}{(x^2+a)^m}$, where $m>1$, integer, and $a>0$.  What is the best way to integrate this function?  Is there more than one way?

Comment: @Dr.MV $2m-2$. :)

Comment: @wltrup Yes.  $2m-2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recurrence relation derived by Jack D'Aurizio in his answer above can actually be solved explicitly for $I_m$. First let me quote it below, but changing the recurrence index to $n$:

> $$
> I_{n+1} = \frac{2n+1}{2n}\,I_{n} + f_n(t)
> \qquad (n \ge 1) \qquad (1)
> $$
>   where
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> I_0 &= t \\[0.05in]
> I_1 &= \arctan(t) \\[0.05in]
> f_n(t) &\equiv \frac{1}{2n}\frac{t}{(1+t^2)^n} \qquad (n \ge 1)
> \end{align}
> $$

Now define the quantity

> $$
> P_{n} \equiv \prod_{k\,=\,1}^{n} \left(\frac{2k+1}{2k}\right)
>            = \prod_{k\,=\,1}^{n} \left(1 + \frac{1}{2k}\right)
> $$

Then, dividing (1) by $P_n$, we find
$$
\frac{I_{n+1}}{P_{n}} - \left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\right)\frac{I_{n}}{P_{n}} = \frac{f_n}{P_{n}}
$$

Since
$$
P_{n} = \left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\right)P_{n-1}
$$
we have
$$
\frac{I_{n+1}}{P_{n}} - \frac{I_{n}}{P_{n-1}} = \frac{f_n}{P_{n}}
$$

Now sum both sides on $n$:
$$
\sum_{n\,=\,2}^{m-1} \left( \frac{I_{n+1}}{P_{n}} - \frac{I_{n}}{P_{n-1}} \right)= \sum_{n\,=\,2}^{m-1} \frac{f_n}{P_{n}}
$$

The LHS telescopes, so
$$
\frac{I_{m}}{P_{m-1}} - \frac{I_{2}}{P_{1}} = \sum_{n\,=\,2}^{m-1} \frac{f_n}{P_{n}}
$$
and
$$
I_{m} = P_{m-1} \left(
\frac{I_{2}}{P_{1}} + \sum_{n\,=\,2}^{m-1} \frac{f_n}{P_{n}} \right) = P_{m-1} \left(
\frac{I_{2}}{P_{1}} - \frac{f_1}{P_{1}} + \sum_{n\,=\,1}^{m-1} \frac{f_n}{P_{n}} \right) = P_{m-1} \left(
I_1 + \sum_{n\,=\,1}^{m-1} \frac{f_n}{P_{n}} \right)
$$
where (1) was used in the last equality to remove $I_2$.

Hence,

> $$
> I_{m} = P_{m-1} \left(
> \arctan(t) + \sum_{n\,=\,1}^{m-1} \frac{t\,(1+t^2)^{-n}}{2n\,P_{n}} \right)
> \qquad (m \ge 2)
> $$

Answer (score 7):

Let:
$$ I_m = \int \frac{dt}{(1+t^2)^m}.$$
We have $I_0=t, I_1 = \arctan t$ and:
$$ I_{m+1}=\int \frac{(1+t^2)-t^2}{(1+t^2)^{m+1}}\,dt = I_m-\int \frac{t}{2}\cdot\frac{2t}{(1+t^2)^{m+1}}\,dt$$
hence, through integration by parts:
$$ I_{m+1} = I_m+\frac{t}{2m}\cdot\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^m}+\frac{I_m}{2m} $$
and we have the recursive formula:

> $$ I_{m+1} = \frac{2m+1}{2m}\,I_m + \frac{1}{2m}\cdot\frac{t}{(1+t^2)^m}. $$

Comment: very nice  general solution +1)

Comment: Nice indeed. +1

Comment: @wltrup: our solutions are very close, I just noticed that we do not really need a trigonometric substitution before performing integration by parts.

Comment: True, but you went all the way. I was too lazy to continue. :)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You might be interested to know that the recurrence can be solved. See my second answer below.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I believe there's a sign mistake in the result, it should be $\frac{2m-1}{2m}$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $a > 0$, let $a = b^2$. Then let
$$x = b\tan\theta$$
$$dx = b\sec^2\theta\,d\theta$$

so that

$$
\int \dfrac{dx}{(x^2+b^2)^m} =
\int \dfrac{b\sec^2\theta\,d\theta}{b^{2m}\sec^{2m}\theta} =
b^{1-2m}\int \cos^{2(m-1)}\theta\,d\theta
$$

This can now be integrated by parts repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Evaluate $I(a)=\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{x^2+a}$ , and then differentiate both sides $m-1$ times with regard to *a*.